# Multiple background images (gradient + sprite)

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

*This relates specifically to the compass framework for SASS.*

I have created a sprite and also a gradient mixin. Is it possible to combine the two on the same item, and if so how?

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;

@mixin light-gradient {
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, $dark 20%, $light 100%));
    color: $dark;
    text-shadow: $light;
}

button {
    @include light-gradient;
    @include icon-sprite(search);
}
```

**Update:**

I've come up with this solution, can anybody improve on it?

```
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";

$icon: sprite-map("icon/*.png");

$light-gradient: linear-gradient(bottom, $shade-2 20%, $shade-3 100%);
$icon-search: sprite($icon, search) no-repeat;

button {
    @include background($light-gradient, $icon-search);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I found it would only work when I gave background() the icon then the gradient (opposite of what you have), like so: @include background($icon-search, $light-gradient);

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `$<map>-sprites` variable to get the sprite map generated by the sprite mixins, like so (based on your original example):

```
@import "compass/css3";

@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;

button {
    @include background(linear-gradient(top, $dark 20%, $light 100%),
                        sprite($icon-sprites, search) no-repeat);
}
```

Not necessarily all that much more elegant (if at all), but another route if you choose to take it. :)